# How to put an image inside a listAdapter

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an Activity and a xml, and I want to put an image inside the listAdapter that I have.

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" >

</TextView>
```

My listAdapter in the Activity:

```
String adapter[] = new String[1];
adapter[0] = "Test";    
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main, adapter));
```

This is just part of the code, actually I have an for() making many lines in the list, my ideia is put in which line a image with diferent colors, like labels according the value inside in which line.
Is that possible?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the method `getView` in the `ArrayAdapter` you created

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  // Customize the view
}
```

Here is a good tutorial about this topic:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/

Comment: Wow, nice tutorial... Thanks!
I've found some videos about it too, I'm posting the link so, if someone has the same doubt here it is:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3mlfG89VDU